# Add break between each CGEventPost

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, events

OK, so I am using the LEAP Motion, if you have not heard of it before it is a device that shoots out lasers which send an image through a cable and it processes that image to give a result in the amount of fingers, hands etc. It shoots this data through frames every millisecond or so (I think).

So what I am doing is detecting if there is one finger above the Leap, then I use this code:

```
CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);

CGEventRef pressedDKeyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)0x02, YES);

CGEventRef pressedDKeyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)0x02, NO);

CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pressedDKeyDown);
CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pressedDKeyUp);

CFRelease(pressedDKeyDown);
CFRelease(pressedDKeyUp);
CFRelease(source);
```

Which simulates the pressing of the 'D' key, and it works! But too many times! Since the LEAP Motion is updated with frame imagery every millisecond or so, therefore the D key is pressed too many times. I want to add a break between each click, preferably around 0.5 seconds between each scheduled event.

Any way to do this? Should I setup an `NSTimer`?

Answer (score 0):

You could call a second method from the method that is called when one finger is detected above the Leap:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(pressDKey) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

That second method is called `pressDKey` and you put the code in there that posts the key press events. Don't forget to put the following in the `pressDKey` method, too:

```
[self cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(pressDKey) object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just record when you posted a key. When later events arrive, check the current time against the last-key-posted time. If insufficient time has elapsed, just ignore the current event.